# Entering input code but doesn't ask me for input when I run

Tags: python

I have this code below:

```
def my_function(username,greetings):
    username = input("enter your name:")
    print("Hello %s , I wish you %s"%(username,greetings))
```

I would expect to be asked for the input when I run it, but it doesn't show the `"enter your name:"`

Comment: Do you ever run your function? You're just defining it in the code you have posted.

Comment: You have a function, you also need to call that function by doing `myfunction(...)`

Comment: why are you passing `username` as a parameter if you are then getting input?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
def my_function(username, greetings):
    print("Hello %s , I wish you %s"%(username, greetings))

username_input = input("enter your name:")
greetings_input = input("enter your greeting:")
my_function(username_input, greetings_input)
```

#### Explanation

`def my_function()` has the function definition which takes two parameters i.e `username` and `greetings` as inputs to the function. The function prints the statement `Hello ..., I wish you ...` with appropriate replacements

When you run the python code, the line `username_input` requests the user for an input of the name and the result is stored in the variable. Similarly with `greeting_input`.

You then have to *call* the function by using the name of the function i.e. *`my_function()`* with the appropriate parameters taken as input. So the function call happens by doing `my_function(username_input, greeting_input)`

All the best with your learning. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. With your explanation I understand a logic I missed so far, so thank you for that.

Comment: Glad it helped. You could mark this answer as accepted indicating that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

great work so far, what you're doing wrong, is the username have to be instantiated before passing it as parameter to the function,

```
# declating the function
def my_function(username,greetings):
    print("Hello %s , I wish you %s"%(username,greetings))

#reading the username from the user input
username = input("enter your name:")

# initiating greetings variable
greetings = 'some greetings'

#calling the function with the previously declared variables
my_function(username, greetings)
```